# How to use ReplicatedMap instead of Map in the Springboot + hzelcast cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

I'm using springboot cache abstraction and hazelcast as a cacahe middleware. When using the annotation @Cacheable, I found out from the HazelcastCacheManager#getCache method that hazelcast uses Map as the data sttucture by default, and I want to use ReplicatedMap as the cached data structure while continuing to use @Cacheable for caching. What should I do?

I used maven to introduce related dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The code I see:

```java
package com.hazelcast.spring.cache;

HazelcastCacheManager#getCache

    @Override
    public Cache getCache(String name) {
        Cache cache = caches.get(name);
        if (cache == null) {
            IMap<Object, Object> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap(name);
            cache = new HazelcastCache(map);
            long cacheTimeout = calculateCacheReadTimeout(name);
            ((HazelcastCache) cache).setReadTimeout(cacheTimeout);
            Cache currentCache = caches.putIfAbsent(name, cache);
            if (currentCache != null) {
                cache = currentCache;
            }
        }
        return cache;
    }
```

You can see code `hazelcastInstance.getMap(name)`.

**20190726 Problem supplement ：**

In fact, we did a simple study before using hazelcast. We need to build a cluster, and we want each node's cache changes to be synchronized to the cache of other nodes, which is the replication mode. Then we saw that the ReplicatedMap in hazelcast basically meets our needs.

We can see from a demo that you can use ReplicatedMap on the code to complete the switch operation, but we prefer to use spring boot cache annotations (such as @Cacheable) to achieve lower coupling (even if you need to convert other cache components later. There is also no need to change the code that uses the cache, just change the different cache configuration).

When using @Cacheable, we found that although the cache is in effect, it is not possible to listen to ReplicatedMap , but Map does. We suspect that hazelcast uses Map as the cached data structure by default, and we found the `com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager#getCache` method. So we want to know how to switch Map to ReplicatedMap.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, it's not configurable.

I see https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/15360. You could implement it yourself and submit a PR ? A bit of explanation of the need would be helpful also.

There is a different consistency guarantee between `ReplicatedMap` and `IMap` to be aware of, (see https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.1/manual/html-single/index.html#replicating-instead-of-partitioning), but for `@Cacheable` that may not be much of an issue.

As an alternative, what about using a near cache ?
(see https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12.1/manual/html-single/index.html#near-cache)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But we need to build a cluster and hope that the cache changes of one node can be copied to the cache of other nodes.
Also, I would like to ask, in your opinion, which one is more consistent with Map and Replicated?

Comment: If you need it today it'll have to be `IMap`. Data is split across the nodes but accessible from all. When a `@Cacheable` entry is created it might be stored on node 2, but node 3 can access it. Each time it does it is transferred, if the network is slow so is this transfer. Tackling the transfer speed might not be viable. But if you add a near cache then once node 3 retrieves an item from node 2, node 3 keeps a hold of it to use again. So the network pain is only once per cached item. `@Cacheable` data doesn't change so consistency worries are gone. But the value needs to be deterministic.